# How do you get the nth child of a class in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors

Normally I would do this in the console:

```
$('element:nth-child(which child)')
```

For a class selector I have tried this:

```
$('.class:nth-child(2)')
```

This doesn't seem to work, is it even possible to get an nth class? It's just that there are 4 lots with the same class name, and there is no way to select it to then get the button I wish to get.

Comment: `$('.class:nth-child(2)')` will definitely work when used in the correct context (demo: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/kcfyt49a/). We can't help you debug why it doesn't work for you without seeing the HTML.

Comment: The `nth-child()` thing refers to an element in relation to its sibling elements with a common parent. It's not for picking one element out of a list of matched elements.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - @Pointy is correct - I believe what the OP is trying to do is get the 2nd sibling that contains a certain class. As an example, say we have the following elements in order: #id1.class, #id2.different-class, #id3.class, #id4.class -- I think what he wants to get in this example is #id3, because that's the 2nd sibling containing the class `.class`. This will not work using nth-child as in your example - I've forked your demo to demonstrate this: https://jsfiddle.net/awqorj7p/

Comment: I understand the issue with that, however without the OP confirming what the HTML looks like it's just a guess. For all we know they could be executing the second line of code before document.ready has fired.

Comment: In the sentence below I clearly asked if it is possible to get an nth class (not nth child class) I wrote nth child as an example. In this situation im not trying to get the child of the class but am trying to get 1 of 4 classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my assumption is correct, you are wanting to look at a group of sibling elements, and get the 2nd instance containing a certain class. As an example, let's say you have the following markup:

```
<div class="class1" id="id1">One</div>
<div class="class888" id="id2">Two</div>
<div class="class1" id="id3">Three</div>
<div class="class1" id="id4">Four</div>
```

And of those siblings, you want to get the 2nd one that contains the class `.class1` (which here would be #id3 - we skip #id2 since that does not contain the class `.class1`). In this case, you can **not** use the `nth-child()` selector - this can only be used with *all elements* (as in `:nth-child(2)`) or *specific element types* (as in `tr:nth-child(2)`).

The way to do what you want is to first filter by class selector, and then use the `eq` method. So in your case you'd want:

```
$('.class').eq(1); // note eq() is zero-based - hence, 1 represents the 2nd child
```

Note that `eq()` is zero-based, so `eq(1)` represents the 2nd child.

Answer (score -2):

This should be done with

```
$(" ... ").get(n);
```

If you want the jQuery object, not the DOM object, you should use

```
$(" ... ").eq(n);
```

This is from the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)